# Need to store my function's results as a dictionary value in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, dictionary

I have 2 functions that read a csv file and count the following as checks:

1. number of rows in that csv
2. number of rows that have a null value in the 'ID' column

I am trying to create a dataframe that looks like this

| Checks | Summary | Findings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Check #1 | Number of records on file | function #1 results (Number of records on file: 10) |
| Check #2 | Number of records missing an ID | function #2 results (Number of records missing an ID: 2) |

function 1 looks like this:

```
def function1():
    with open('data.csv') as file:
        record_number = len(list(file))
        print("Number of records on file:",record_number)
function1()
```

and outputs "Number of records on file: 10"

function 2 looks like this:

```
def function2():
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', low_memory=False)
    missing_id = df["IDs"].isna().sum()
    print("Number of records missing an ID:", missing_id)
function2()
```

and outputs "Number of records missing an ID: 2"

I attempt to create a dictionary first and create my dictionary

```
table = {
   'Checks' : ['Check #1', 'Check #2'],
    'Summary' : ['Number of records on file', 'Number of records missing an ID'],
    'Findings' : [function1, function2]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
df
```

However, this is what the dataframe looks like:

| Checks | Summary | Findings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Check #1 | Number of records on file | <function function1 at 0x7efd2d76a730> |
| Check #2 | Number of records missing an ID | <function2 at 0x7efd25cd0b70> |

Is there any way to make it so that my Findings column outputs the actual results as seen above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your functions so they `return` values, not output them, that is do

```
def function1():
    with open('data.csv') as file:
        record_number = len(list(file))
        return record_number
```

and

```
def function2():
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', low_memory=False)
    return df["IDs"].isna().sum()
```

and call these functions like so

```
table = {
   'Checks' : ['Check #1', 'Check #2'],
    'Summary' : ['Number of records on file', 'Number of records missing an ID'],
    'Findings' : [function1(), function2()]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
df
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you're printing the function objects, and not their results:

`function1 != function1()`

So for your case you need:

```
table = {
   'Checks' : ['Check #1', 'Check #2'],
    'Summary' : ['Number of records on file', 'Number of records missing an ID'],
    'Findings' : [function1(), function2()]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
df
```

Edit: Oh damn and I also missed what the other user commented. You definitely need to `return` a value from your functions as well :)

Answer (score 0):

For expected ouput add `return` with `f-strings` to both functions, in DataFrame call functions with parentheses:

```
def function1():
    with open('data.csv') as file:
        record_number = len(list(file))
        return f"function #1 results (Number of records on file: {record_number})")


def function2():
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', low_memory=False)
    missing_id = df["IDs"].isna().sum()
    return f"function #2 results (Number of records missing an ID: {missing_id})")


table = {
   'Checks' : ['Check #1', 'Check #2'],
    'Summary' : ['Number of records on file', 'Number of records missing an ID'],
    'Findings' : [function1(), function2()]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
```

Solution with one function:

```
def function():
    with open('data.csv') as file:
        record_number = len(list(file))
        missing_id = df["IDs"].isna().sum()
        
        return [f"function #1 results (Number of records on file: {record_number})"),
                f"function #2 results (Number of records missing an ID: {missing_id})")]


table = {
   'Checks' : ['Check #1', 'Check #2'],
    'Summary' : ['Number of records on file', 'Number of records missing an ID'],
    'Findings' : function()
}
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
```